# Do I need to repeat the subject after a semicolon splitting two sentences that have the same subject in formal written English?

Tags: subjects, semicolons

Do I need to repeat the subject after a semicolon splitting two sentences that have the same subject in formal written English?

For example:

> He talked to the owners, which was understandable; paid the bills, which was not expected; and, did not even ask for the money back, which was unbelievable.

Should I add the subject "he" after each semicolon on the example above?

Comment: Your sentence, though long, is fine. If you are going to repeat the *he*, then you may as well go all the way and split the sentence in three.

Comment: The function of the semicolons here is not to join independent clauses, but rather to separate items in a list of three. Such separation is normally effected by commas; but here, where each item is attached to a non-restrictive relative clause, set off by a comma, the item separators rightly become semicolons instead.

Comment: I would not have a comma in "and, did not"

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to repeat the subject after a semicolon?

No.

He talked to the owners, which was understandable; paid the bills, which was not expected<sub>comma</sub> and<sub>no comma</sub> did not even ask for the money back, which was unbelievable.

The second semicolon would appear the be “the Oxford Semicolon” :)

Answer (score -1):

Probably, this would have been frowned upon historically, but

- He talked to the owners – which was understandable, paid the bills – which was not expected, and did not even ask for the money back – which was unbelievable.

should not have attracted opposition. (The comma after *and* is not really appropriate.) Here, the confusion of commas in different roles is avoided, retaining just the listing commas. Brackets (pairs) could be used instead of single dashes to offset the parentheticals. Adding the deleted *he*'s to the sentence as given would satisfy most traditionalists, and is not too clunky (separate sentences would probably be not smooth-running enough).

BUT as the supercomma usage of the semicolon is now generally accepted, your version (with one comma less) should not be rejected. But then there *are* diehards.

Comment: Using *unpaired* dashes to demarcate parenthetical material seems barbarous beyond anything in the original post.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: I think Edwin's (slightly "creative") orthography is streets ahead of the positively barbarous **; and, did not even ask...** in the original. Which to my eye is still pretty awful even when that comma is removed. I'm fine with the idea that the closing dash after a parenthetical can be "implicit" if we encounter a comma that's obviously *not* part of the parenthetical element. All we're trying to do is ensure the reader can parse the text without having to work at it (and without "distractingly unusual punctuation", on which point obviously opinions will differ).

Comment: Dashes are always unpaired to offset parentheticals terminal in either sentences or tacked on to the end of independent clauses.